# bluetooth mac-to-mac file exchange limits

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I have two physically adjacent macbook pro machines.  One has a 3.8GB file (XCode 3.2.5 installer) that I want to copy it to the other macbook. (That file is no longer available from iOS Dev connection). I've connected the machines by bluetooth, and initiated the file send.  But it appears to hang.
Can someone explain why this is doomed, and what would be a faster way?  I'm considering ftp to my web server, and ftp it back to the other mac.
Thanks.

Comment: FAQ refers to: software tools commonly used by programmers.  I think XCode qualifies.  Not sure why this was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to go through the ethernet network (wired or wifi) See [this](http://gigaom.com/apple/mac-101-sharing-files-between-2-macs/)